# Dynamic VideoView Height Based on Parent Width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm trying to size a `VideoView` to the parent container width and then set the height to maintain a 4:3 aspect ratio.  I've seen some answers that recommend extending the `VideoView` class and overriding `onMeasure`, but I don't understand the parameters that I'm getting or how to use them:

```
package com.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MyVideoView extends VideoView {

    public MyVideoView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyVideoView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyVideoView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        Log.i("MyVideoView", "width="+widthMeasureSpec);
        Log.i("MyVideoView", "height="+heightMeasureSpec);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Result (on Nexus 7 tablet):

```
02-13 21:33:42.515: I/MyVideoView(12667): width=1073742463
02-13 21:33:42.515: I/MyVideoView(12667): height=1073742303
```

I'm trying to achieve the following layout:

Tablet (portrait):

- VideoView width - full or nearly full screen.
- VideoView height - maintain 4:3 aspect ratio given the width
- ListView - appears below the VideoView to select a video to play.

Tablet (landscape):

- ListView - appears on the left of the screen, used to select a video to play.
- VideoView - appears on the right of the screen and should fill with remaining width and the set height to maintain the 4:3 aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = getDefaultSize(mVideoWidth, widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = getDefaultSize(mVideoHeight, heightMeasureSpec);

            /**Adjust according to your desired ratio*/
    if (mVideoWidth > 0 && mVideoHeight > 0) {
        if (mVideoWidth * height > width * mVideoHeight) {
            // Log.i("@@@", "image too tall, correcting");
            height = (width * mVideoHeight / mVideoWidth);
        } else if (mVideoWidth * height < width * mVideoHeight) {
            // Log.i("@@@", "image too wide, correcting");
            width = (height * mVideoWidth / mVideoHeight);
        } else {
            // Log.i("@@@", "aspect ratio is correct: " +
            // width+"/"+height+"="+
            // mVideoWidth+"/"+mVideoHeight);
        }
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

}
```

Where mVideoWidth and mVideoHeight are the current dimension of the video.
Hope that helps. :)

Comment: I don't really have current dimensions of the video as the player is created when the tab is created and the user then clicks a list item to play a video.  Videos can either be 640x480 or 320x240.  This seems to work ok:`int width = getDefaultSize(0, widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = getDefaultSize(0, heightMeasureSpec);
     setMeasuredDimension(width, width/4*3);`